# how to open infowindow through a button

Tags: google-maps, button, infowindow

I'm trying to open an infowindow through a button located in another infowindow.

I made the button, but I need help on creating the trigger or event to do that.

Button:

```
  <input name="enviar" type="submit" id="form1" value="Reservar"/>
```

Code for opening the infowindow by clicking the marker, I need that to open by clicking on the button. Please help.

```
var form = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: myLatLng,
  draggable: true,
  icon: icon
}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(form, 'click', showform);
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function showform(event) {
  var contentString =  '<div style="width:160px;height:140px;"> <b>LOTE 1</b> <img  src="img/terreno1.png" width="113" height="72" /> <br>450m²<br> <p style="color:#F00;"> Indisponível </p></div>';

  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infoWindow.open(map);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put a [demo with solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sasha_thor/H7EAD/9/) on JSFiddle

Here is HTML part

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:800px;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var infoWindow;
$(document).ready(function(){
  var default_center = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = { zoom: 8, center: default_center, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: default_center, map: map });
  marker1.content = '<input name="enviar" type="submit" id="form1" value="Reservar"/>';
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    showform(marker1, function(){
      $("#form1").click(function(){
        showform(marker2);
      });
    });
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.297, 150.144), map: map });
  marker2.content = '<div style="width:160px;height:140px;"> <b>LOTE 1</b> <img  src="img/terreno1.png" width="113" height="72" /> <br>450m²<br> <p style="color:#F00;"> Indisponível </p></div>';
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    showform(marker2);
  });
});

function showform(marker, handler) {
  if(infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
  infoWindow.setContent(marker.content);
  infoWindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
  infoWindow.open(map);
  if(handler){
    google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', handler);
  }
}
```